Returning search results from a NextJS API endpoint incrementally
I have an /api/search endpoint in my NextJS application which kicks off 5 different searches for a given query string. Some return much sooner than others, so I want to return results as they're available. It seems like the right solution is to return a ReadableStream from the endpoint.
I've made this change, and it works with a single inner search. However, when I try to return multiple JSON chunks, they all get stuck together and returned at once. This defeats the purpose of parallelizing the return, while also generating invalid JSON.

I found this GitHub comment which suggests that you have to use TextEncoder.encode() to have chunks properly stream, so I am now doing that. Unfortunately, nothing has changed.
The initial example uses pull() instead of putting everything inside of start(). I tried that, but all the results are STILL being returned run together.
It looks like the results are always returning in the same order, presumably because of the for loop. I actually want them to return as they're completed. Many examples use an async iterator, but I don't think that will work for me because I don't know what order to put the items in at iteration creation time.

How can I return valid JSON in chunks as the results are available?
/app/api/search/route.js
export async function GET(request) {
    const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams
    const query = searchParams.get('q')
    const year = searchParams.get('year')

    // Define the tasks to run concurrently
    const tasks = [
        async () => ({ type: 'coordinates', result: await parseCoordinates(query) }),
        async () => ({ type: 'address', result: await runAddressSearch(query) }),
        async () => ({ type: 'metro', result: await runMetroSearch(year, query) }),
        async () => ({ type: 'road', result: await runRoadSearch(year, query) }),
        async () => ({ type: 'district', result: await runDistrictSearch(year, query) }),
    ];

    // Set up a ReadableStream to respond incrementally
    const stream = new ReadableStream({
        async start(controller) {
            const taskPromises = tasks.map((task, index) =>
                task().then(
                    (result) => ({ status: 'fulfilled', index, ...result }),
                    (error) => ({ status: 'rejected', index, error })
                )
            );

            const encoder = new TextEncoder()

            // Process each task as it finishes
            for (const taskPromise of taskPromises) {
                const result = await taskPromise;
                console.log("promise result:", result)

                if (result.status === 'fulfilled') {
                    if (result.result.length > 0) {
                        controller.enqueue(encoder.encode(
                            JSON.stringify({ type: result.type, result: result.result }) + '\n'
                        ));
                    }
                } else {
                    controller.enqueue(encoder.encode(
                        JSON.stringify({ type: result.type, error: result.error.toString() }) + '\n'));
                }
            }

            controller.close();
        },
    },
    // Not sure if this cache block is necessary or correct?
    {
        highWaterMark: 1,
        size(chunk) {
            return 1;
        },
    });

    return new Response(stream)
}

